# Elegant way to delete rows which are not referenced by other table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables (Tasks and Timeentries), which are connected by a foreign key (TimeEntries.TaskID references Tasks.ID)

Now I'd like to delete all rows from Tasks which are not referenced by the TimeEntries table. I thought that this should work:

```
DELETE FROM Tasks WHERE ID not IN (SELECT TaskID FROM TimeEntries)
```

But it affects 0 rows, even though there are a lot of unreferenced rows in the Tasks table.

What might be the problem here? Of course I could write an SP which iterates all rows, but it seems like this could be done in a one liner.

I guess this is one of those sleeptime underflow errors. Please help!

Comment: Do you get the expected results if you just run the SELECT subquery on its own?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There's one notorious gotcha for `not in`.  Basically, `id not in (1,2,3)` is shorthand for:

```
id <> 1 and id <> 2 and id <> 3
```

Now if your `TimeEntries` table contains any row with a `TaskID` of `null`, the `not in` translates to:

```
ID <> null and ID <> 1 and ID <> 2 AND ...
```

The result of a comparison with `null` is always `unknown`.  Since `unknown` is not true in SQL, the `where` clause filters out all rows, and you end up deleting nothing.

An easy fix is an additional where clause in the subquery:

```
DELETE FROM Tasks 
WHERE  ID not IN 
       (
       SELECT  TaskID 
       FROM    TimeEntries 
       WHERE   TaskID is not null
       )
```

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how to get around this?

Comment: @DOK: Sure, one way added to the answer.  SQLMenace posted another good one

Comment: Indeed. This might be old, but I found it on Google and I must say I love the way you explain it. Very clear! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 28):

One way, this will take care of the 'problem' you are having with nulls (see link below for more info)

```
DELETE FROM Tasks 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TimeEntries 
                  WHERE TimeEntries.TaskID  = Tasks.ID )
```

To understand the problem you are having, take a look at [Select all rows from one table that don't exist in another table](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#4)

Comment: This answer is more elegant I guess.

Answer (score 10):

Since you are running SQL 2008, you can use the nifty new merge syntax.

```
MERGE Tasks AS target
USING TimeEntries as Source ON (Target.TaskID=Source.TaskID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN DELETE;
```

Comment: +1: A bit overkill in this case, but it's certainly useful to know about the merge command. I did not even know something like this existed.

Comment: Why do you think it is overkill? It is pretty much made for tasks like this (matching up rows between tables).

Comment: What about its performance compared to former solutions? Does it have any advantages or is this the supported way to do such actions? Thx

Comment: Had to match two columns and this was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old, but I wonder why nobody mentioned a delete query as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835%28v=sql.100%29.aspx#snippetGroup7). So, for reference:

```
DELETE FROM Tasks
FROM Tasks LEFT OUTER JOIN
    TimeEntries ON TimeEntries.TaskID = Tasks.ID
WHERE TimeEntries.TaskID IS NULL;
```

This syntax is not ISO-compatible, so will only work for T-SQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
  Delete FROM Tasks 
       WHERE not Exists 
          (SELECT 'X' FROM TimeEntries where TimeEntries.TaskID  = Tasks.ID)
```

The SQL Above should delete all the Rows from Tasks where the Task.ID does not exist in the Time Entries Table.  I would run it as a select Statement first to test :)