# How to delete rows that fail a foreign key i want to introduce

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

In a given SQL Server 2008 table I have a disabled foreign key constraint that should be enabled. I cannot enable this constraint because there are rows in this table that conflict with this foreign key. These rows are invalid.

Is there a simple trick that removes data that is conflicting with this constraint?

Comment: as you didn't reply to my answer, what exactly was wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to manually remove all the row that doesn't respect the constrain: probably you will need a T-SQL statement to get all the row you need to remove(perhaps using an outer join) then remove them

Comment: I tried this, but the FK is a bit complex. I was searching for a different approach.

Comment: you have to do it yourself. Have a look at the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312876/elegant-way-to-delete-rows-which-are-not-referenced-by-other-table

Answer (score 2):

This would be one way to do it

**SQL Script**

```
BEGIN TRAN

DELETE FROM Detail    
OUTPUT DELETED.*  -- Verification
FROM   Detail d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Master m ON m.PK = d.FK
WHERE  m.PK IS NULL

ROLLBACK TRAN -- Change to commit when verified.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the offending data with this query:

```
DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS WITH ALL_CONSTRAINTS
```