# How can I optimize this particular query?

Tags: mysql

In order to delete the rows that do not exist in table1 from table2, I am running the following query (each table holds around 1 million rows):

```
DELETE table2
FROM   table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.col2 = table1.col2
WHERE  table1.col2 IS NULL
```

It is taking a long time. For that, I created a stored procedure that use a temporary table (temp_col2 is smaller than table2, because it has one column instead of 20 columns that table2 has).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_old_rows()
   BEGIN
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_col2 select col2 from table2;

        delete table2 FROM  table2
        LEFT JOIN temp_col2 ON table2.col2 = temp_col2.col2
        WHERE col2 IS NULL;

       DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_sepet_id;
   END
```

But it's still so slow. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312876/elegant-way-to-delete-rows-which-are-not-referenced-by-other-table

Comment: Do you have an index on table1.col2? Are the data types of the 2 joining columns the same?

Comment: @Bohemian yes I have index on col2 in the both tables, and the same data type

Comment: @Imanez that's all good then. Next question: how many rows meet the criterion... How many rows are expected to be deleted?

Comment: @Bohemian about 239438 rows

Comment: Create table my_new_table as SELECT...join..equals. Drop old table. Rename new table

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, your query, which looks fine, will delete about 1/4 of the 1 million rows. That's a lot of work to do, especially if you're using the default row-level locking.

Reduce the locking overhead by wrapping the statement in a transaction and lock the table in exclusive mode while you perform your deletions:

```
START TRANSACTION;
LOCK TABLES table2 WRITE;
DELETE table2
FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.col2 = table1.col2
WHERE table1.col2 IS NULL;
UNLOCK TABLES;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I use MyIsam as storage engine, which means I have table level locking

Comment: Yes, it took same time like when I execute query without transaction (because MyIsam ignores transaction)